# Unable to fetch data from MySQL database with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fetch-api

I'm able to post successfully to MySQL database with Fetch API. The problem I'm having is trying to retrieve data from my database.

client.js:

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const date = document.querySelector('#date');
const submitbtn = document.querySelector('#submitbtn');
const commentOutput = document.querySelector('#message');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const comments = document.getElementById('message')


form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    sendMessage();

    let formMessage = new FormData(form);

    formMessage.append('api-key', 'myApiKey');


    fetch('http://localhost:5502/superhero', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ comments: comments.value })

    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ comments: comments.value }))
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
})



submitbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5502')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('success')
            } else {
                console.log('failure')
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data =>
            console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log('Error'))


    var newUser = document.createElement("div");
    var newName = document.createElement("h5");
    var newDate = document.createElement("h5");
    var newMessage = document.createElement("h6");

    newName.textContent = comments.value;
    newDate.textContent = message.value;
    newMessage.textContent = message.value;

    output.appendChild(newName);
    output.appendChild(newDate);
    output.appendChild(newMessage);

    output.appendChild(newUser);
})
```

The problem here is the fetch method under the submitbtn:
Output:
[image]

index.js:

```
router.post("/superhero", function(req, res) {

    const user = req.user;
    const comments = req.body.comments;

    sqlDatabase.query("INSERT INTO comments (user_id, comments) VALUES (?, ?)", [user, comments],
        function(error, results, fields) {
            console.log(results);
            console.log(comments);
            console.log('This is: ', comments)
            console.log(error)
            if (error) throw error;

        });
})


router.get("/superhero", authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res, err) {

    sqlDatabase.query("SELECT users.username, comments.comments, comments.date FROM users INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id=comments.user_id",
        function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            console.log(error);
            res.render('superhero');

        })
})
```

I want to retrieve that data under router.get

Hope this is enough details. Thanks in advance. Noob by the way.

Comment: Have you tried logging the actual error?

Comment: Try `fetch('http://localhost:5502/superhero')` since that's the route you've configured but FYI, `res.render('superhero')` probably won't respond with JSON so `response.json()` will probably fail

Comment: How about `res.json(results)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the results I wanted. I just created another api for retrieving data from my server file and changed
this:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:5502/superhero')
```

to:

```
  fetch('http://localhost:5502' + '/get_messages')
```

```
app.get("/get_messages", function(request, result) {
    sqlDatabase.query("SELECT users.username, comments.comments, comments.date FROM users INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id=comments.user_id",
        function(error, results) {
            result.end(JSON.stringify(results));
            console.log(results);
        });
});
```

So I have a route for rendering a view, and one for retrieving the data

Comment: I believe my answer the solution to your except that you didn't add the `Server` side rendering to the question. Since you were having issue with the `fetch` and I answered that, however, I also added details to how could you achieve different rendering.

Comment: I hear you, but thanks, you did help me. Initially, I thought my problem was just on the client-side until you pointed out I was not sending JSON objects back.

Comment: At `StackOverflow` we (helper) invest time to answer your question and if somebody will post his own answer with a slight change, it surely isn't a good idea. Also, should accept answers on your previous questions as well by clicking on the middle of the number(0)

Answer (score 0):

The `res.send` actually send back the `JSON` response

```
    router.get("/superhero", authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res, err) {

    sqlDatabase.query("SELECT users.username, comments.comments, comments.date FROM users INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id=comments.user_id",
        function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            console.log(error);
            res.send({heros: results}); //<-- send back the JSON response

        })
})
```

Also, you can add condition if you're rendering on the server side as well

```
if (req.accepts('json')) {
  res.send({hero: 'superhero'}); // <-- try sending back JSON object but rather a string
 // OR
 res.send({heros: results});
else {
 res.render('superhero');
}
```

If you're using `Express` then you can use `response.json` method as well.

Comment: `res.json()` is more appropriate though it's unlikely OP actually wants to respond with the literal string `"superhero"`

Comment: @Phil "superhero" string should be converted to object. See my updated answer

Comment: Why not use `results`?

Comment: @Phil it's upto him whatever he returns but it should be an object

Comment: Okay, so I've tried your answer, it respond with the strings. How would I render the route and send the json together. I'll handle the json for display on the clientside.

I'll tick your answer in the mean time, cuz it is helping.

Comment: @Samora.M Do you mean `Server` side rendering when you access `/superhero` in the browser?

Comment: Yes. I'm just seeing a literal string on-page, instead of my actual page.
When trying to send json and render it doesnt allow me cuz I cant set multiple headers after sending to client.

Comment: @Samora.M see my `else` condition in the answer where I render the `response` to the browser.

Comment: But that just renders page, without sending back any json data though right? And then this: res.send({heros: results});, sends back json without rendering the actual page. 

Sorry if there's somehting flying over my head.

Comment: Yeah that's true. One will send the `json (res.send)` response if it is `fetch` request otherwise it will `render (res.render)` to the browser